# AC blower turns on and off 1 or 2 times per second

Tags: hvac

I have a Carrier Weathermaker 8000. When using the A/C and the house is below the temperature called for by the thermostat, the blower motor randomly turns on and after 10 seconds or more will start to cycle off and on 1 or 2 times per second. I simultaneously hear a clicking sound and loud shaking/vibration from the constant off and on process. What can cause this?

Comment: Check the connections for the blower relay.

Comment: I was going to suggest check the relay but checking the connections makes more sense.  The normal vibration of a relay could shake wires loose.